# Abstract class constructor call overridable method

Tags: c#, moq, abstract-base-class

I try to create a good testable repository class to use with Moq. I don't want duplicate my selector methods (`GetAll`, `Get`, ...). My implementation works fine but SonarSource reports an error [RSPEC-1699](https://rules.sonarsource.com/csharp/RSPEC-1699) Does anyone know of a better implementation?

```cs
var areas = new Area[] { ... };
var areaRepositoryMock = new Mock<BaseAreaRepository>() { CallBase = true };
areaRepositoryMock.Setup(m => m.Initialize()).Returns(areas);
```

**Base Class**

```cs
public abstract class BaseAreaRepository
{
    protected Area[] _areas;

    protected BaseAreaRepository()
    {
        this._areas = this.Initialize();
    }

    public abstract Area[] Initialize();

    public Area[] GetAll()
    {
        return this._monitoredAreas;
    }

    public Area Get(int id)
    {
        return this._areas.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id.Equals(id));
    }
}
```

**MyAreaRepository**

```cs
public class MyAreaRepository : BaseAreaRepository
{
    public override Area[] Initialize()
    {
        return //Load data from an other source
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you intend to override anything other than `Initialize`? And where does `Initialize` get its data from?

Comment: @ScottHannen I only override Initialize at the moment, the data can source are a database or a webservice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *RSPEC-1699 Constructors should only call non-overridable methods* doens't have anything with the unit tests it will remain there regardless how you are going to test it.

> Does anyone know of a better implementation?

I would like to propose another approach in order to avoid this violation and make your code even more testable.

The idea is instead of the `base` class use composition and DI principle.

```
public interface IAreaContext
{
    Area[] GetAreas();
}

public class AreaRepository
{
    private IAreaContext _areaContext;

    protected BaseAreaRepository(IAreaContext areaContext)
    {
        _areaContext = areaContext;
    }

    public Area[] GetAll()
    {
        return _areaContext.GetAreas();
    }
}
```

Then you could define multiple implementations of `IAreaContext` and injext:

```
public class MyAreaContext : IAreaContext
{
    public Area[] GetAreas()
    {
        return //Load data from an other source
    }
}

public class MyOtherAreaContext : IAreaContext
{
    public Area[] GetAreas()
    {
        return //Load data from an other source
    }
}
```

Now when you have this setup  repository could be easily testable for different behaviors of the context itself. This is just an example to demonstrate idea:

```
//Arrange
var context = new Mock<IAreaContext>();
context.Setup(m => m.GetAreas()).Verifiable();
var sut = new AreaRepository(context.Object);

//Act
var _ = sut.GetAll();

//Assert
context.Verify();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test just the base class, then I would create a unit test specific implementation of the class, and just provide any helper functions to test the protected ones.  Basically what you have done with `MyAreaRepository` but as a `private class` within the test class.

Comment: No i want test an other class with a dependency to the base class

Comment: I would still do the same trick, just derive your test class from `MyAreaRepository` and override the `Initialize()` function with some mocked data.